# My website is not showing after deploy in firebase how to solve this

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have complete all process

1. Firebase Login
2. Firebase init
3. Firebase deploy

now finally i got a link https://testing-37553.firebaseapp.com/
but my website not showing so what should i have to do.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried to deploy? Are have you updated your `firebase.json` with the correct folder that contains your build/dist folders?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default `index.html` page that is created by the CLI when you create a new project.

You should adapt this `index.html` page as you whish (i.e. by modifying the HTML/CSS/JS code of this page, in your local project directory) and re-deploy the project with

```
firebase deploy
```

or

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Comment: How to modify the index.html?

Comment: In the Firebase project on your local machine.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your firebase.json file and make sure that the 'public' key under "hosting" is set to "build" like below:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build"
}
```

It was likely set to "public" by default when you ran firebase init. In which case it would look like this:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public"
}
```

The problem with the default is that React places all your static assets in the 'build' directory when you run npm run build, so that is where you want to point firebase to.

Comment: Why isn't this configuration auto-generated? I had to manually add this in for the project to upload.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the similar issue, my application was on react built using create react app. I was trying to deploy via firebase but getting the default page of firebase then i figured out that I havent build my application so firebase was not able to find my application html file and hence it was trying to deploy the default one.

I solved it by running yarn build, then when I do firebase init selected "hosting" option . After this step while selecting folder to deploy rather public I selected "build" and this solved my problem and my application got hosted. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 4):

For Angular 8.

If the name of your project is "ManyuDictionary".

1)Run firebase login.

2)Run firebase init and choose:

a) hosting

b) What do you want to use as your public directory? dist/ManyuDictionary

c) Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes.

Firebase will now write configuration info to firebase.json and project 
information to .firebaserc.

3)Run ng build --prod.This will replace the default index.html in dist/ManyuDictionary.

4)Run firebase deploy.

And here is your website [https://manyudictionary.firebaseapp.com].

Comment: Your solution works. The user should make sure to go to this link: https://project-name.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 7+, **here is the straight forward solution that works for me as of August-2019**
Just delete the `index.html` file at the root of your `/dist` folder.
Then, copy all the content inside the `directory(named like your project main project folder's name)` found in your `/dist` folder

Lastly, rerun `firebase deploy`

Enjoyed!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked for me as of 9/17/2020**

**1-** Finish the **firebase init** steps.

**2-** Add this to your **firebase.json** file:

```
//"public": should be, dist + project name on your computer
//"site": should be the app name which you created on your firebase cloud

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/your-project-name",
    "site": "firebase-project-name",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**3-** ng build --prod

**4-** firebase deploy

Answer (score 0):

Firebase asks wehn you type `firebase init hosting`.

```
File dist/your-project/index.html already exists. Overwrite?
```

Press

```
NO
```

And you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow firebase Hosting steps, but not solve your problem.Then you can follow this step for solving your problem:

1. Deploy your project in netlify.
2. Take the live project link from netlify.
3. Go to firebase > your project > Hosting > Dashboard.
4. Click the `Add custom domain` Button.
5. Paste the netlify project live link in input box.
6. Click the `Continue` button.
   That's ok.